# How to make a description table

Tags: tables

how do I make a table like this one? 
thank you
[image]

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do you already have some code to share?

Comment: You might have a look [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) for an introduction into tables in LaTeX.

Comment: As an aside, vertical lines in tabulars are frowned upon....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%showframe,
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
{
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| l | L |}
    \hline
Titre           & xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx            \\
    \hline
xxxxx           & xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx            \\
    \hline
xxxxx           & xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx  xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx  xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx \\
    \hline
xxxxx xxxxx     &   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, 
                              nosep, topsep = 0pt, partopsep  = 0pt,
                              before = \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},
                              after  = \vspace{-\baselineskip}]
            \item   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx 
            \item   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
            \item   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
                    xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
                    xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
            \item   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
                    xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x 
                    \end{enumerate}                 \\
    \hline
xxxxx xxxxx xx  &   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx  xxxxx   \\            
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or exploit `booktabs`:

[image]

```
   \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l L }
    \toprule
Titre           & xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx            \\
xxxxx           & xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx            \\
xxxxx           & xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx  xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx  xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx \\
xxxxx xxxxx     &   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, 
                              nosep, topsep = 0pt, partopsep  = 0pt,
                              before = \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},
                              after  = \vspace{-\baselineskip}]
            \item   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx 
            \item   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
            \item   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
                    xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
                    xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
            \item   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx
                    xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx x 
                    \end{enumerate}                 \\
xxxxx xxxxx xx  &   xxxxx xxx xx x xxxxxxx  xxxxx   \\            
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Since you are already loading `booktabs` wouldn't it be nicer to use `\toprule` and so on instead of `\hline`?

Comment: yes, and remove vertical lines :-) or delete booktabs :-( ... its remind of one my old answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant solution with the `wide` option of `enumitem`. I'll demonstrate for the last two rows. I added some vertical padding to the cells with `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}
{\makegapedcells\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|>{\arraybackslash}X|}%
\hline
Scénario nominal & \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, nosep, before = \leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
\item L’utilisateur demande la réinitialisation de son mot de passe.
\item L’utilisateur introduit son email.
\item Un email contenant un lien de réinitialisation lui est envoyé.
\item L’utilisateur clique sur le lien et arrive sur un formulaire où il saisit son nouveau mot de passe.
\item Une fois le mot de passe modifié, l’utilisateur peut se connecter avec son nouveau mot de passe.
\end{enumerate} \\
\hline
Scénario d’exception & Si l’email fourni est inexistant, l’utilisateur sera alerté. \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]
**Added:**

I propose another solution, with the `framed` package, and no rule except the frame:

```
\setlength{\FrameSep}{2pt}\begin{framed}\makegapedcells\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\bfseries}l>{\arraybackslash}X}%
Scénario nominal & \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, nosep, before = \leavevmode\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}]
\item L’utilisateur demande la réinitialisation de son mot de passe.
\item L’utilisateur introduit son email.
\item Un email contenant un lien de réinitialisation lui est envoyé.
\item L’utilisateur clique sur le lien et arrive sur un formulaire où il saisit son nouveau mot de passe.
\item Une fois le mot de passe modifié, l’utilisateur peut se connecter avec son nouveau mot de passe.
\end{enumerate} \\
Scénario d’exception & Si l’email fourni est inexistant, l’utilisateur sera alerté. \
\end{tabularx}
\end{framed}
```

[image]